# Trying to set up 2nd router on home network running TorGuard VPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

I'm trying to set up a second router on my home network to use a VPN (TorGuard) to provide a network connection that is apparently in another country.

My main router, connected to my ISP, is connected to a second router running dd-wrt through a LAN port (I had no luck through the WAN port on this 2nd router).

I have used the startup script provided by TORGuard for the dd-wrt router but get no results, my local IP through this router (over wifi) is still my geographical location.

I am no networking expert and a bunch of the options are completely opaque to me so I even need help knowing exactly what questions to ask :D I have managed to set this second router up so that I can access the internet through its wifi, rather than the main router, but I want to be able to change my apparent location.